# Magento 2 - Catalog Price Rules Time

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to add time handle to price rules (by default there is only date).
What I did is:
1. In database, table catalogrule, I changed columns from_date and to_date to datetime
2. In form, added datetime picker to fields from_date and to_date.

Dates are saved correctly in database but what next? I'm trying to make those rules work in real life but those rules are working just like before (only for dates, not for time). Anyone?